# cannot read property 'map' of undefined react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6N9c.png)

The error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' is thrown when the map function in the Product component is executed.

I'm following the react Native tutorial, and I keep running into an issue when passing the value from the state of one component into another component.
I'm following the react Native tutorial, and I keep running into an issue when passing the value from the state of one component into another component.

i used axios to get the data

ProductScreen

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import MenuProduct from '../components/Product/MenuProduct';
import MainHeader from '../components/Header/MainHeader';
import {POPULAR, Top_Sell} from '../data';
import ProductItem from '../components/Product/ProductItem';
import instance from '../routes/instance';

const ProductScreen = () => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await instance('/api/products', {
        method: 'GET',
      });
      setProduct(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <MainHeader />
      <MenuProduct list={Top_Sell} />
      <ProductItem list={product} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

ProductItem

```
import React from 'react';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';

const ProductItem = ({product}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {product.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <ProductCard
            id={item._id}
            image={item.image}
            title={item.title}
            price={item.price}
            item={item}
            key={index}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductItem;
```

ProductCard

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, ScrollView, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import {colors, sizes, spacing} from '../../constants/theme';
import AddItem from '../../utils/AddItem';

const CardHeight = 220;
const ProductCard = ({props}) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      return (
      <View
        style={{
          marginLeft: spacing.l,
          marginBottom: spacing.l,
          marginRight: spacing.l,
        }}>
        <View>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: colors.white,
              borderRadius: sizes.radius,
              shadowColor: colors.black,
              shadowRadius: 4,
              shadowOpacity: 0.1,
              shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
            }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                borderRadius: sizes.radius,
                overflow: 'hidden',
                flexDirection: 'row',
              }}>
              <Image
                style={{
                  borderRadius: sizes.radius,
                  width: 160,
                  height: CardHeight - 60,
                  resizeMode: 'cover',
                }}
                source={props.image}
              />

              <View style={{marginTop: spacing.l}}>
                <View style={{marginLeft: spacing.l, marginBottom: spacing.s}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color: '#FA4A0C'}}>
                    {props.title}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{marginLeft: spacing.l}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 14, color: '#8b8989'}}>
                    {props.price}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft: 130}}>
                  <AddItem />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      ); })
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

I have tried several ways on stackoverflow but I can't figure it out

Comment: If you use `<ProductItem list={product} />` in ProductScreen, then you should use `const ProductItem = ({list}) => {` in ProductItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be list in ProductItem component and use list.map because when you sending prop in ProductItem you are sending list

```
import React from 'react';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';

const ProductItem = ({list}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {list.length > 0 && list.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <ProductCard
            id={item._id}
            image={item.image}
            title={item.title}
            price={item.price}
            item={item}
            key={index}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below syntax for passing data from parent to child component.

```
<Child parentToChild={data}/>
```

Here, we are passing the data in the child component as data.

`data` is the data we have to pass, and `parentToChild` is the prop's name.

Next, it's time to capture the data in the child component. And it's very simple.

Here, there can be two cases.

**Case 1:** If you are using a functional component, simply catch the `parentToChild` in the parameters.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Child({parentToChild}) {
    return (
        <div>
            {parentToChild}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Case 2: If you have a class component, then just use `this.props.parentToChild`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Child extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.parentToChild}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```